# Laravel get value from 2 column with relationship one to one

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-6

I have 2 tables and have relationship one to one. Second table use a FK from first one, and I want to display a list with all values .

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
   $listOfPersons = new Person();
   $listOfRegisters = new  Register();

   $listOfRegisters->listOfPersons()->associate();
   return $listOfRegisters;
}
```

**In Register Model**

```
public function people(){
    return $this->hasOne(Person::class);
}
```

**In Person Model**

```
public function register(){
    return $this->hasOne(Register::class);
}
```

Comment: Which is your "second table"?

Comment: First one is for persons, the second one are another info about each person,in Register, and I use a FK between them.

Comment: hi, have you checked [Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)? you can use `with` to query a model along with its relationships. e.g. `Person::with('register');`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want a list with all pairs of values, it should be enough with this code:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $registers = Register::all();
    $list = [];
    foreach($registers as $register){
        array_push($list,['register'=> $register, 'person'=>$register->people]);
    }
    return $list;
}
```

But remember you can just have the list of registers and access the person via the relationship. Moreover, you should change the `hasOne` relationship to `belongsTo` in register.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Great, thank you!, I will change the order person-register, from your code, but is what I need!

Comment: Happy to help! :)

Comment: why don't you use leftjoin? why do you use foreach?

Comment: Because you're already retrieving both elements via the relationship and this way you separate persons and registers. But that would be a good solution too. @AliSharifineyestani

Comment: Now I see, with this method I get person { }, info twice, witch is not good.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to use leftjoin. (not foreach and php loop)

Because:

> The alternative of handling this inside your PHP code with a foreach
>   loop is unattractive for several reasons. First, you would probably
>   need to bring in all information from both tables, which is wasteful
>   from both a memory and network usage point of view. Then, even after
>   you have brought in the data, you would be relying on PHP to perform
>   the join. PHP wasn't really designed for in house database operations,
>   and cannot use something like an index to speed up the process.

So you can write your query like:

```
User::leftJoin('register', 'register.user_id', '=', 'id');
```

However, I prefer to add a scope in my model for this situation

```
<?php

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    public function scopeRegister($builder)
    {
       $query = $query->leftJoin('register', 'register.user_id', '=', 'id');
       return $query;

    }
```

and in my controller

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $records = User::register()->get();
}
```